# How to create custom user pool on cognito, and connect this to your application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I would like to use the `out-of-the-box` user account creation with cognito, and am able to do that. But I would like to add custom attributes.
Now, is there a way, using the terminal, that you can ask amplify to use the user pool you have created, instead of the default one that it generates for you?

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include source code formatted to better understand your issue and find the proper solution. 
Please check the documentation [on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the advice Carlos - I just did not have any source code to share for this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you do not have to create a Cognito User/Identity Pools when using AWS Amplify (simply, do not run `amplify add auth`).

And even if you have one created by default, you can still manually configure Amplify to use desired resources for authentication as:

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab',
        region: 'XX-XXXX-X',
        identityPoolRegion: 'XX-XXXX-X',
        userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234',
        userPoolWebClientId: 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2m3',
        mandatorySignIn: false
    }
});
```

Just put the proper values of your project. For further options for manual configuration, you can have a glance at the [Amplify Auth docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#manual-setup).

Comment: Thanks for this @vahdet. 
I managed to download a book on serverless stack that is brilliant and has a lot of answers to the many questions I have.
https://serverless-stack.com
Being a meteor user (and the meteor documentation is phenomenal) - I struggled with the AWS documentation. I probably just have not persevered enough.